# Fetch Id of record after create in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript code which creates a **Case** from an Opportunity, on button click.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")} 

var myQuery = "SELECT  Application_Entitlement_ID__c FROM Account WHERE Id = '{!Opportunity.AccountId}' limit 1";
result = sforce.connection.query(myQuery); 
records = result.getArray("records"); 

var roleName = "CaseRole";
var qr = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id, Name FROM CaseTeamRole WHERE Name = 'Requestor'");
var crRecords = qr.getArray("records");
var rec = crRecords[0];

if(records[0]){ 
  var relatedAccount = records[0]; 
  try{ 
    var recToCreate = new sforce.SObject("Case");

    // select Case Record Type
    var recordTypeQuery = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Name,Id from RecordType WHERE developername = 'WE_Application'");
    var recordTypeQueryResult = recordTypeQuery.getArray("records");
    recToCreate.RecordTypeId = recordTypeQueryResult[0].Id;

    // select Queue as owner 
    var queueNameQuery = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Queue.DeveloperName, QueueId from QueueSobject WHERE Queue.DeveloperName = 'Wex_Europe_Customer_Services'");
    var queueNameQueryResult = queueNameQuery.getArray("records");
    recToCreate.OwnerId = queueNameQueryResult[0].QueueId;

    recToCreate.AccountId = '{!Opportunity.AccountId}';  
    recToCreate.Subject = '{!Opportunity.Name}';  
    recToCreate.Origin = "Customer Application";
    recToCreate.Opportunity__c = '{!Opportunity.Id}';
    recToCreate.User__c = '{!Opportunity.OwnerId}';

    // select Entitlement from Account field
    recToCreate.EntitlementId = relatedAccount.Application_Entitlement_ID__c;

    var result = sforce.connection.create([recToCreate]);


    // add business requestor to Case Team Role
    var ct = new sforce.SObject("CaseTeamMember");
    ct.MemberId = "{!$User.Id}";
    ct.parentId = result[0].id;
    ct.TeamRoleID = rec.Id;
    alert('Logged In User: '+ct.MemberId);
    alert('Case ID: '+ct.parentId);
    alert('TeamRoleID: '+ct.TeamRoleID);

    var result = sforce.connection.create([ct]);
    alert('Successfully Added to Case Team');


    // check that Case has been created
    if(result[0].success == "true"){
      location.reload();
    }
    else{
      alert("An Error has Occurred. Error: " + result[0].errors.message);
    }
  }
  catch(e){
    alert("An Error has Occurred. Error: " + e);
  }


}
```

I now need to use the Id of the newly created Case to populate the Parent Id field of a Case Team Role which I'm creating later in the code. But the below doesn't pick up the Id of the new record.

```
var ct = new sforce.SObject("CaseTeamMember");
ct.parentId= result[0].Id;
```

An alert tells me that -

> result[0].Id is undefined

I've spent the afternoon looking for documentation which explains how to fetch the Id and can't find any examples?

Comment: This example https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_more_samples.htm has the id field in all lower case when referencing it in JavaScript i.e. `result[0].id`. Try that.

Comment: Yes I was about to say that... Use "id" instead.

Comment: Thanks but it looks like that wasn't the issue in this case, I have the same error if I can the Id to id.

Comment: Can you show the complete code including the part that generates error? Also, don't forget to @mention our names. We get notification due to that.

Comment: @heisenberg I've updated the question with the full code but I can only tag one user, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: You are using if(records[0]) -- This won't give a boolean output. This statement returns the complete record. You should use if(records.length>0).

Comment: @heisenberg I've made that change but I still get the same message Id undefined in my alert.

Comment: So you made both the changes(id and boolean) and still get the error? Need to check this thoroughly.

Comment: @heisenberg yes, just to be clear - I've included my change to the records[0].id; portion in my question - please check that I've changed the part of the code which you were referring to and I have updated the if( statement too (but not in my question). Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @heisenberg I really hope you haven't started your checks yet! I replaced the variable result[0].id; with records[0].id; and that was why there was still an issue. Just to be clear, it was the case of the i that was the issue (but not the if statement) - sorry about that. Could you please post your answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: Great man ... It works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a record is created by AJAX synchronous call, please use "id" to get the record Id. Since javascript is a case sensitive language, we have to be cautious about that. In your case, replace all the "Id" by "id.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use a Flow?

Button URL:

/flow/FLOW_UNIQUE_NAME?var_OpportunityId={!Opportunity.Id}&retURL=/{!Opportunity.Id}

**Flow:**
Now, do a Lookup based on the Opportunity Id to grab those fields. Make the variable in your flow "var_OpportunityId" or it wont sync to the button.

After you find the values u need (account, owner, etc.), do a Record Create on the Case Object with your new Ticket.  At the end of this little screen, you have the option to create a new variable for the "Created Case's Id".  Do so.

Now, you want to do a Record Create on the Team Members.  You can do this with any of the logic you wanted to in your javascript.

Easy as pie **:)**

Comment: Also, just realized its you Alex, hi! :)

Comment: Hi! You've got a thing for these flows haven't you! So this is probably a stupid question but just to check, if I use a Flow for this, the user would only have to click the button and the Case & Case Team would be created automatically (they wouldn't have to enter any data on a Screen element)?

Comment: Alex, yes you can.  You dont need a Screen element on a Flow.  If you have a Flow without a Screen element, they click the button and are redirected to the Opportunity.  All the magic happens in the backend without any user interaction.

Comment: That's good to know, I've finally got the code working but I'll definitely use this option next time, debugging JavaScript is a nightmare! Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = sforce.connection.create([recToCreate]);

if(result[0].getBoolean("success")){
    sforce.debug.log("new account created with id " + result[0].id);
} 
else{ 
    sforce.debug.log("failed to create account " + result[0]);
}
```

Comment: After making the changes that I've suggested in my edit, I get an error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined.